# Howto add a string prefix

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script that when started, will monitor the clipboard and then paste that into a text file as below, that works fine, but what I would like and cannot figure how to do is to add a bit of text before the clipboard text..

So for eg.

Clipboard that is pasted is `image_003_lon`
I would like to add `Dept-342` to the beginning of the line then the pasted text. so should read , `Dept-342 image_003_lon`

The *Dept-342* text is *static*, this would not change.

```
function Get-ClipboardText(){
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $tb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $tb.Multiline = $true
    $tb.Paste()
    $tb.Text

$clipboard = Get-ClipboardText | Out-File -Append $tempfile -encoding ASCII
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a *format string* to append the text. Also, you don't have to create a form to access the clipboard since there is a [`Get-Clipboard`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt736727.aspx) cmdlet ;-):

```
'Dept-342 {0}' -f (Get-Clipboard) | Out-File -Append $tempfile -encoding ASCII
```

Comment: The horrors in their original code! They created a text box and called `Paste`, though, instead of a `Form`. Nevertheless, they could just have used the `Clipboard` class instead, e.g. when on PowerShell < 5.

Comment: Thanks for that, it works just as expected. The Function for clipboard was done a while ago, and to be honest, i am still pretty new to powershell, but am learning everyday. 

Sites like this are really awesome, many thanks again.